# Kendo Datasource response is empty

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I am new to Kendo UI. I am trying to read the remote data and display in the screen. I am able to see the remote json data by accessing the URL in the browser. But when I try to alert() the response data inside kendo UI, it is empty.

here is the sample code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var shareDataSource;
    var viewModel;
    function searchByVin() {
        var vin = $("#vinNumber").val();
        shareDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost:9080/portal/programexcep/resources/request/vin/"+vin,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                model: { id: "Id" }
            },
            requestEnd: function(e) {
                var response = e.response;
                var type = e.type;
                alert(type);
                alert(response.length);
            }
        });
        shareDataSource.read();
        alert(vin);
        alert(kendo.stringify(shareDataSource.data()));
    }
</script>
```

The JSON data is

```js
{"Id":10,"FirstName":"John Smith","vin":"html5"}
```

as the response in the browser. The `alert(kendo.stringify(shareDataSource.data()));` is empty 
and the  `alert(response.length);` is also undefined.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `shareDataSource.read();` is asynchronous which means that you invoke read but data is not immediately available. You can use [`fetch`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-fetch) instead that executes a portion of code when the data is available. Your code would be:

```
shareDataSource.fetch(function() {
    alert(vin);     
    alert(kendo.stringify(shareDataSource.data()));
});
```

There is also a problem in `requestEnd` function: you try to get the `length` of `response` but in the `model` definition you say that `data` field is called `data` so your server should be returning something like:

```
{ 
    "data" : [ 
        { "Id" : 1 },
        { "Id" : 2 }, 
        { "Id" : 3 }
    ]
}
```

and then for accessing the length you should do `response.data.length`